# Images are inserted into the wrong place

Tags: bug, markdown, uploader

When inserting an image, I often type some text and then leave 3 blank lines:

[image]

I position the cursor on the second of those three blank lines. The I click the image button and select an image. The image is not inserted at the cursor, it's inserted here:

[image]

It's a network wide issue - it did it as I was writing this post.